# Groovy shorthand if else operator

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to set a variable in a .gsp file with an object been passed to the view from the controller. 
'*item*' is an object in this case with an attribute called '*sequence*'
So what I'm trying to do is set the var '*action*' to the value of item.sequence and if item.sequence is null then set action value to the string "new".

```
<g:set var="action" value= "${item.sequence?item.sequence:'new'}"/>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the value of item.sequence and "new" together. 
Does anyone know how I can do this shorthand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [Elvis Operator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-ElvisOperator(?:))

`value="${item.sequence ?: 'new'}"`

This will return `item.sequence` as long as it is *truthy*. If `item.sequence` is *falsy*, then it will return the second expression.

Comment: I'm still getting both values in one string. so item.sequence = /. my action variable looks like this. action="new/"

Comment: It is appending item.sequence to 'new'?  I think there is something else going on here because what you have should work.

Comment: You were right it was something on the server end that was screwing with it.